# Custom UniqueId for merge replication on sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, merge-replication

When doing merge replication, is the column `ROWGUIDCOL`  compulsory?  Can I use a custom column I have created that will be unique across all databases?

Does this mean I have to use `GUID` as my primary key or can i have a `gUID` column and my custom id column as well?

When I try to create a merge replication, it wants to add a guid column and I am not sure if thats what i want to do.

Any suggest a stragety to create a merge replication?  I really want to avoid using a guid as my primary key on all tables...this would also create a alot of work for our application

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags stand alone.  Adding `[sql]` and `[server]` to your question doesn't mean the same thing as adding `[sql-server]`!  Always be sure to read the helpful tag descriptions that appear when you type tag names, and select your tags with care.

Comment: Merge replication adds this GUID column but you dont have to make it your primary key. this GUID column is only added for Replication purposes and nothing else.

Comment: thanks...great..does it need a timestamp column or is that automatic?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Considerations for Merge Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151206.aspx), each published table requires a GUID column with the ROWGUIDCOL property set and a unique index.

> Merge replication uses a globally unique identifier (GUID) column to
>   identify each row during the merge replication process. If a published
>   table does not have a uniqueidentifier column with the ROWGUIDCOL
>   property and a unique index, replication adds one. Ensure that any
>   SELECT and INSERT statements that reference published tables use
>   column lists. If a table is no longer published and replication added
>   the column, the column is removed; if the column already existed, it
>   is not removed.